# QGIS - viewing Raster stored as an out-db raster, raster2pgsql out-db, showing bounds only

Tags: qgis, raster, postgis, postgresql

I'm storing raster data as an out-db option in our PostGIS database for use in QGIS.

I am loading the raster via raster2pgsql:

```
raster2pgsql -s 28350 -C -I -F “path\[image_name].tif" [schema1].[tablename] -R | psql -h localhost -d spatialDB -U postgres -p 5432
```

This seems to 'work' as it enters a new table in my schema.

However, when I try and view the data in QGIS via the PostGIS browser and/or via the DB Manager, it  shows nothing. However, I can 'zoom' to the image bounds in QGIS, but the raster doesn't appear.

The out-db physical raster sits on our file server.

Is there a setting I need to add on import to the raster2pgsql command? Or is it a driver problem in QGIS?

I'm using QGIS 3.20.3-Odense with PostgreSQL+PostGIS 13.4 Windows.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I suspect it may be something to do with the nature of your GeoTIFF. Perhaps adding more details could help; e.g. is it tiled?

Comment: Is the first character, that is not a double quote in `“path\[image_name].tif"` only a typo in your question?